# Microsoft Exchange 2013 Shared calendars on Mobile Devices

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013, calendar

I have an Exchange 2013 server with a user shared calendar. Can't configure an iPhone to view the shared calendar. It doesn't appear on the MS Outlook app, nor the MS OWA app.

Any suggestions:

My goal is to share a calendar and set permission for some users to view only and others to edit, all to have smartphone access.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible natively. The only way to access a shared calendar is to have full access to the mailbox and its password.

There are some third party apps which can access it for you, I haven't tried any, but I know they (did) exist. Check the App Store.

Simon.